# Can regexec be used to find matches using a binary file?

Tags: c

Given a binary file with the structure

```
unsigned int number1;
unsigned int num_rec;
acct_info_t acct[num_rec];
```

where acct_info_t is

```
typedef struct
  {
      char name[40];
      int number;
      float balance;
  } acct_info_t;
```

Can a regular expression search of names using regexec be done without iterating through records and checking each name? 
I thought "no" as there can be a "0" byte anywhere in the file and regexec will terminate before looking at the whole file. Besides, wouldn't one need to load the entire file first, making it impracticable?  So iterating is best?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice it was in Chegg! lol. However, Chegg uses regexpr, which has the match positions and lengths are in characters unless useBytes = TRUE is used, when they are in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

After discussing this with others, iterating through records and using regexec per record is needed.